# Jenkins subversion "check out fresh copy" vs "wipe out workspace"

Tags: .net, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm having an error on a build jenkins build job that can be resolved by doing a workspace wipe out before build.

As SCM we're using subversion with check-out strategy: *always check out a fresh copy*.
I assumed that this strategy was the equivalent of:

1. wipe out workspace
2. svn checkout

Apparently I'm overlooking something cause my problem is only resolved when I manually wipe out the workspace. Can anyone explain this why "fresh copy check out" doesn't do the job?

Extra info:

- my svn checkout out is to "." inside the workspace
- the build project is a .NET solution
- the build error: *CSC : error CS0016: Could not write to output file*. It's about an intermediate output file.
- I know that the workspace wipe out is a workaround but nevertheless I want to understand why manual wipe out does the job and fresh svn check out doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding and experience with Jenkins and SCM (but for completeness with another SCM  - Integrity) is that checking out a fresh copy means, that all files from the SCM archive are fetched, but that all files in the workspace not coming from the SCM are left untouched. This is i.e. useful if you have files in the workspace that should not go into the SCM for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks @hpschr for your answer. This is also what I experienced by now.

Comment: A little bit misleading or even wrong is the comment in Jenkins below the _always check out a fresh copy_ option which says "Delete everything first, then perform 'svn checkout'. While this takes time to execute, it ensures that the workspace is in the pristine state.". If you really want a clear workspace there is Jenkins plugin. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683914/is-there-any-way-to-cleanup-jenkins-workspace